# Why don't the molecules in the air "observe" the electron in the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Question says it all. The air should also interact with the electrons which should result in wave function collapse.

Comment: We do it in vacuum

Comment: The double slit results are observed even when we do it in air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-slit experiment with electrons can only be done in vacuum, unless the dimensions of your double-slit experimental set-up is much smaller than the free mean path of the electrons in air, which is below $0.5\mu m$ in air under normal conditions. Otherwise only very few electrons will reach the screen. Inelastic scattering destroys the coherence of the electron waves and thus also the interference pattern on the screen.